# How to fix "list indices must be integers, not type"

Tags: python

How to fix this code:

```
def CheckRow(arr, row, num):
    for col in range(9):
        if (arr[row][col] == num):
            return True
    return False

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not type
```

Comment: What is row? What is arr?

Comment: def CheckRow(arr, row=0, num=0):for col in range(9):
  if (arr[row][col] == num):
   return True
 return False

Comment: this is a function in a class

Comment: row is a integer type (argument)

Comment: @TMK95 It obviously isn't, or you wouldn't be getting that error.

Comment: You need to post the code that's calling the function so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: http://codepad.org/reU944ek

Comment: I want to solve Sodoku Game but it's not work :)

Answer (score 2):

`row` or `col` is not integer, one of them is a `type`. Check them, probably one of them is equal to `None` because you said it's a function in a class.

```
def SolveSudoku(arr):
    row = int
    col = int
    if (not FinZero(arr, row, col)):
        return True
    for num in range(1,10):
        if (IsSafe(arr, row, col, num)):
            arr[row][col] = num

            if (SolveSudoku(arr)):
                return True

            arr[row][col] = 0
    return False
```

In this part you see `row = int`. This is the worst definition I've ever seen, probably the writer of the code tried to define an empty integer. Basically change this to `row = int()`.

Check this

```
row = int

row_int = int()

print (type(row))

print (type(row_int))
```

Output;

```
>>> 
<class 'type'>
<class 'int'>
>>>
```

See first one is `type`, second one is an `integer`.

Comment: It obviously isn't `col`, since that comes from `for col in range(9)`.

Comment: Can you help me this code to solve sodoku game by backtracking. This link : http://codepad.org/reU944ek

Comment: @TMK95 I solved your problem Im going to edit my answer

Comment: @TMK95 If it's solved your problem please check my answer as the correct answer

Comment: Of course. Show me your answer, please :D

Comment: I converted my code from C++ :D

Comment: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not type" solve. But i have a new problem is :
return ((not CheckRow(arr, row, num)) and (not CheckCol(arr, col, num)) and (not CheckBox(arr, row - row%3, col - col%3, num)))
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: @TMK95 Then this code block is not working, it's a recursive function and depth must be show clearly. I suggest you find another clear solution.

Comment: Because it work fine on C++. http://codepad.org/h9ljCqc3

Comment: Can you help me convert that code from C++ to Python ???

Comment: @TMK95 I don't know C++ so I can't.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not with the code but with the input.

Most likely you passed the argument `row` as something other than an integer.

Your code should also be formatted like so:

```
def CheckRow(arr, row, num):
    for col in range(9):
        if (arr[row][col] == num):
            return True
    return False
```

**EDIT**

I reviewed the code that you linked in GLHF's post.

### Conversion problems

Here is my version, keeping all your naming conventions in your C++ code.

```
UNASSIGNED = 0
N = 9

def FindUnassignedLocation(grid, row, col):
    for row in range(N):
        for col in range(N):
            if grid[row][col] == UNASSIGNED:
                return True
    return False

def UsedInRow(grid, row, num):
    for col in range(N):
        if grid[row][col] == num:
            return True
    return False

def UsedInCol(grid, col, num):
    for row in range(N):
        if grid[row][col] == num:
            return True
    return False

def UsedInBox(grid, boxStartRow, boxStartCol, num):
    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(3):
            if grid[row + boxStartRow][col + boxStartCol] == num:
                return True
    return False

def isSafe(grid, row, col, num):
    return False not in (UsedInRow(grid, row, num),
                 UsedInCol(grid, col, num),
                 UsedInBox(grid, row - (row % 3), col - (col % 3), num)):

def printGrid(grid):
    for row in range(N):
        for col in range(N):
            print "%2d" % (grid[row][col])

def SolveSodoku(grid):
    row = 0
    col = 0
    if not FinZero(grid, row, col):
        return True

    for num in range(1,10):
        if isSafe(grid, row, col, num):
            grid[row][col] = num

            if SolveSodoku(grid):
                return True
            else:
                grid[row][col] = UNASSIGNED
    return False

grid = [
[ 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1 ],
[ 7, 0, 9, 0, 3, 8, 0, 0, 4 ],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
[ 1, 0, 0, 9, 4, 0, 3, 0, 6 ],
[ 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 0 ],
[ 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9 ]
]
if SolveSodoku(grid):
    printGrid(grid)
else:
    print "No solution exists"
```

The problem you had was that when converting from C++ to Python, the statement in C++

```
int row, col;
```

Would actually instantiate the variables with a default value of 0. Therefore, it is equivalent to Python's

```
row = 0
col = 0
```

### Maximum Recursion Depth

This issue would be supposedly resolved in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/maximum-recursion-depth).

> It is a guard against a stack overflow, yes.
>
> You can change the recursion limit with [`sys.setrecursionlimit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit), but doing so is dangerous -- the standard limit is a little conservative, but Python stackframes can be quite big.

However, when you increase the maximum recursion depth, it did warn that it may crash Python (which it did on my computer), I suggest you take a look at one of the solutions to solving recursive sodoku [here](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html).

Comment: His code **is** formatted like that. He just didn't paste it into SO correctly. Wait for the edit.

Comment: because CheckRow is a function in class, it will have "self" argument. But your code is not work ! :D